# Web scraping with pagination doesn't return all results

Tags: web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

I am trying to scrape Indeed.com but having a problem with pagination.
Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
class JobsNySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs_ny'
    allowed_domains = ['www.indeed.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=analytics&l=New%20York%2C%20NY&vjk=7b2f6385304ffc78']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath("//td[@id='resultsCol']")
        for job in jobs:
            yield {
                'Job_title': job.xpath(".//td[@class='resultContent']/div/h2/span/text()").get(),
                'Company_name': job.xpath(".//span[@class='companyName']/a/text()").get(),
                'Company_rating': job.xpath(".//span[@class='ratingNumber']/span/text()").get(),
                'Company_location': job.xpath(".//div[@class='companyLocation']/text()").get(),
                'Estimated_salary': job.xpath(".//span[@class='estimated-salary']/span/text()").get()
        }

        next_page = response.urljoin(response.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Next']/@href").get())

        if next_page:
           yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

The problem is that according to Indeed there are 28,789 jobs that match my query.
However, when I save what I've scraped to csv file, there are only 76 rows.
I also tried:
next_page = response.urljoin(response.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination-list']/li[position() = last()]/a/@href").get())
but the result was similar.
So my question is what I am doing wrong while handling the pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem is not with the pagination, it's that you only get one job from each page.
2. It's better to do the `urljoin` after the if statement to avoid errors.

```py
import scrapy


class JobsNySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs_ny'
    allowed_domains = ['www.indeed.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=analytics&l=New%20York%2C%20NY&vjk=7b2f6385304ffc78']

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath('//div[@id="mosaic-provider-jobcards"]/a')
        for job in jobs:
            yield {
                'Job_title': job.xpath(".//td[@class='resultContent']/div/h2/span/text()").get(),
                'Company_name': job.xpath(".//span[@class='companyName']/a/text()").get(),
                'Company_rating': job.xpath(".//span[@class='ratingNumber']/span/text()").get(),
                'Company_location': job.xpath(".//div[@class='companyLocation']/text()").get(),
                'Estimated_salary': job.xpath(".//span[@class='estimated-salary']/span/text()").get()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Next']/@href").get()

        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you, SuperUser! It solved my issue. I tried both 'jobs = response.xpath('//div[@id="mosaic-provider-jobcards"]/a')' and mine 'jobs = response.xpath("//td[@id='resultsCol']")' with url join after the statement but only 'id="mosaic-provider-jobcards' worked. Do you know, by any chance, why it might be the case?

Comment: `response.xpath("//td[@id='resultsCol']")` will get you the container for the jobs,, but not the jobs themselves. So the for loop will have only one iteration and you'll get just the first job for each page.

Comment: Thanks again, @SuperUser , for helping me to understand it!

Comment: @shq No problem